# VideoView problems in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have been searching and trying for about 2 weeks now to be able to get a video player in my android app.

I have tried many solutions, and even youtube API, but it just wont work.
So now i'm hoping someone can look at the code, and explain what i'm doing wrong, so that i can learn this :)

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="no.test.videotest.MainActivity">


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
package no.test.videotest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        String vidAddress = "https://ia800201.us.archive.org/22/items/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

The only thing i get when i upload this to my phone is a black videoplayer with no controls and no video.

Hope someone can tell me what is wrong here.
Thanks.

Comment: checking manifest INTERNET permission

Comment: I have that. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
String vidAddress = "https://ia800201.us.archive.org/22/items/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vidAddress));
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);//add this line 
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
vidControl.setAnchorView(videoView);
videoView.setMediaController(vidControl);
videoView.start();
```

Also make sure your address contain a valid video

Comment: When i here change Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress); with: videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriString));

Should i then change String viAddress above to String vidAddress?

Comment: Thanks alot man. That works just great :) Now i can study the code and learn from it :)